# jsonarray request with parameters

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have a php webservice that returns a json array using `json_encode(array("moviemakers"=>$rows)).` I need to make the json array request from android with parameters.

I saw this:

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), 
        listener, errorListener);
}
```

When I use it in my code, it generates an error. 
Could anyone guide me where to put the above snippet in my code?

Comment: Plesae provide a bit more information. What exactly did you try? What is your error message? Additionally you should try to format your source code.

Comment: please consult http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/ to get a basic understanding about how to use Volley rather than posting random code you don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of a JsonObjectRequest:

```
 private void volleyRequest(String url){
        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.i(LOG_FLAG, response.toString(4));
                    //parseJSON
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    //handle exception
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                //handle error
            }
        });
        //adding request into the queue
        ApplicationClass.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,"someTag");
    }
```

here you can find a really nice tutorial about volley:
[Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had gotten answer to the question